# Does somebody knows a T-SQl query to obtain the SQL Server Users and their DB associations and permissions?

Tags: sql-server-2000

Does somebody knows if its possible to build a T-SQL query to obtain the SQL Server Users ,their DB associations and  permissions?

**this is in SQL server 2000**

i will appreciate!!

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about sp_helplogins?